# Why does async and await not returned a resolved promise outside of the function?

Tags: javascript

I have an async function called getCat with await being used inside of it.  When the console log of the response gets executed inside of its function then it logs a resolved promise expected.  But if I call this from another function displayCat and log the result from the entire getCat function then it returns a promise.  But the result should be the same at this point so why am I getting two different types of console log responses?

```
var getCat = async () => {
  const result = await fetch('https://cataas.com/cat')
  console.log('response: ', result);
  return result;
}

var displayCat = () => {
  console.log('getCat() : ', getCat())
}
```

[image]

Comment: getCat returns a Promise that is resolved only once the fetch promise resolves - that's how Promises work ... async/await does NOT make asynchronous code synchronous as you seem to think it does ... it's called **A**sync/await ... not sync/await

Comment: But why does the response always log a resolved promise then?  How do I get displayCat() to do the same when calling getCat() without using .then()?

Comment: the resolved promise is the one you awaited for, so of course it's resolved. The pending one is the one you returned from getCat

Answer (score 1):

async functions implicitly return a Promise so it needs to be awaited like any other.

Comment: Is there a way to have getCat() in displayCat() return the promise resolved without using .then()?  The way it is for the response console.log I have in the image above?

Comment: Yes, mark `displayCat` as `async` and `await` the call to `getCat`: `console.log('getCat() : ', await getCat())`